# One established server reports "Invalid SID" for a new Samba user

Tags: linux, samba, openldap, sid

We have two linux samba servers authenticating against LDAP that have been working fine for some time. Recently I added a new user to LDAP. He can log in fine to one server, but the other reports an "invalid SID" id (`passdb/passdb.c:lookup_global_sam_name(596)`).

His SID follows the same pattern as everyone elses, and it works on the other server. What could be going on here?

- working server is Fedora 8, Samba Version 3.0.33-0.fc8
- problem server is CentOS 5.3, Version 3.0.33-3.7.el5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this only affected the one person, but I was able to fix it:

1. run `net getlocalsid` on the working server
2. in LDAP, set the `sambaSID` of the `sambaDomain` object for the misbehaving server to the value above
3. restart samba on the naughty server

Now all users can connect to both servers.